# Enable white in jsLint in Sublime for all files

Tags: javascript, sublimetext3, jslint

If I add `/*jslint white: true*/` to my javascript code, jsLint stops complaining about using tabs instead of spaces. I would like to enable it globally so I do not have to repeat myself in every file. To edit jsLint's settings you can go to `JSLint.sublime-settings - User`.
I have added following to this file

```
{
    "white" : true
}
```

However, jsLint is still complaining about using tabs. Is it possible to configure jsLint settings globally?

I am using Sublime Text 3 3083 on OS X 10.11.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this.

Preferences > Package Settings > JSLint > Settings > User

```
{
    "jslint_options": "--white"
}
```